# Is there a way for me to create a folder and place a JSON file in the mobile local storage both Android and iOS in React Native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, local-storage

I am creating an app that should download data from the Api and store the data in a specific folder in the JSON file on the local storage of the mobile . I have searched for several days and still didn't find any support for the question.

Technology: React Native.
Platform: Both Android and iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use react-native-fs library : [Github link](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs)